# locking orientation does not work on ipad ios 8 swift xcode 6.2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I locked the app orientation to portrait from the general app setting like this

[image: portrait]

but still when i run my application on ipad, it rotates!?

so where should i lock the orientation ?

why apple added this feature to settings, while it is not working !?

**UPDATE:**

I tried to implement this viewController as the general for all the viewController as well.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class GeneralViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
        UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
    }


    override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
        return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait
    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

this pic taken from the main navigationController of my app.

[image: Pic of answer 1]

still did not work!

how on earth this thing works?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You don't need extra code, I'm working on Xcode 7.0.1, I noticed that when I lock screen orientation to only portrait, it locks only in iPhones, to lock it in iPads also, you need to select iPad from Devices (instead of Universal) and check portrait and uncheck the others and then return Devices to Universal again, as I found that Universal only reflect in iPhones, it maybe some kind of bug in Xcode.

Comment: Absolutely good answer. How the heck we should know that? :D. It is one of a good finding.

Comment: The mistake was having the device selection as universal, if you change it to iPad, you'll see the orientation different. So change that.

Comment: I cannot upvote this enough. I was going nuts trying to fix this.

Comment: Did anyone file a radar on this?

Comment: And still the same confusion even in Xcode 9! Checking each device orientation before going universal worked :) tnx

Comment: I literally tried everything in iOS 11 and this just saved me. Not so obvious solution to figure out, thanks for sharing!!!

Comment: It works but error occurs when uploading the build file to app store it says iPad must support all orientations

Comment: I wanted to lock orientation on iPhone but not iPad and this worked perfectly. But I think it's a bit unclear to the developer.

Comment: Actually, I only support iPad devices and still the orientation cannot be locked to landscape. I was able to lock it to portrait. But not Landscape. I selected Landscape left and Landscape right. Any clue as to why this happens?

Comment: Thanks for this! I think it's no bug, but it needs to be set in the plist as explained by @Dave Stevens below

Comment: Cannot believe it's still a bug so far (tested on Xcode 10.1)

Comment: This truly needs more upvote ! What's the point of setting things in code if it is overriden...

Comment: Thanks for sharing, solved a long time mystery for me... Thanks!

Comment: Unbelievable. Still relevant for xcode 11, Thank you

Answer (score 8):

You can override your view controller property  [shouldAutorotate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621419-shouldautorotate?changes=_3)

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false 
}
```

If your view controller is embedded in a Navigation controller you can create a custom Navigation controller:

```
class PortraitNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return false 
    }
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: You can create a custom View controller and add it there

Comment: ah thats sounds better, i was checking for solution like the proxy appearance to change it once and it takes effect all over the project

Comment: Is it embedded in a Navigation controller or a TabBar controller?

Comment: yes I use navigation controller and tabBar in some controllers

Comment: Try adding  the supported interface orientation to your Navigation Controller

Comment: Note: The layout that appears at your screen shot has nothing to do with it

Answer (score 8):

I also had same problem. What worked for me was -> Select iPad instead of Universal in Device Type -> Uncheck the other three options except Portrait -> Select Universal again. Done.

Answer (score 5):

This would be a comment added to Mohammed Elrashidy solution but I don't have the reputation to make comments. I am using XCode 9.1 and Swift 3.

My app requires some graphing screens to autorotate but all the other screens to remain fixed. My issue was that the "iPad" device configuration in General > Deployment Info was configured inconsistently with the iPhone and Universal devices. I had "Portrait", "Landscape Left" and "Landscape Right" checked for iPhone and Universal but all of the orientations checked for iPad (including "Upside Down"). Simply unchecking "Upside Down" caused the iPad device to honor the shouldAutorotate and supportedInterfaceOrientations calls in my Swift logic.

My Info.plist now looks like the following and I can programmatically turn autorotation on or off for the iPad.

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Perfect solution, thanks! Setting this in the plist is most likely the better alternative

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to add something else you need to do, after fixed the issue following the above solution:

In XCode, make sure you also check the "Requires Full Screen" checkbox under General > Targets.

Reference:
[iPad Multitasking support requires these orientations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32559724/ipad-multitasking-support-requires-these-orientations)

Comment: Under-rated comment, after trying 10+ answers, this is the one that finally worked. Also required adding code to the ViewController. XCode 12.

Answer (score 1):

Since the XCode changed a lot in these 5 years, I found an easy way to handle it when I ran into the same issue that even I configured the Device Orientation to only allow "Portrait", the restriction is not working in iPad device.

So in newly created project, need go to **Targets->Info->Custom iOS Target Properties-> Supported interface orientations(iPad)**. Then remove the layouts you do not need, then the trick will work.

Answer (score 1):

Open Info.plist, under "Supported interface orientations (iPad)" remove the items you don't need.